# Waiting for one browser to complete action and continue in another browser in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, handle, window-handles

Scenario

I have two applications one is my main order placement website and another coupon generation site . In between my order placement scenario, I have to open a new browser window with a completely new user agent and other settings and create a coupon, grab coupon value and come back to the previous window and apply the coupon.

Sample Code :

```
WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
driver2.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver2.get("URL");
driver.get(URL);
System.out.println(URL);
```

Comment: I don't know your scenario but can you create the coupon and store the value before even starting script 1? Then insert the coupon value at the proper time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your problem was making the first `webdriver`wait until the second one is finished getting the coupon code.

For this my suggestion would be using threads and make the first one wait for the second one to finish.

Here is your `Thread` class. What it will do will fall under the `run()` method.

```
class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;
    private String coupon;
    ThreadDemo( String name){
        threadName = name;
        System.out.println("Creating " +  threadName );
    }
    public void run() {
        WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
        //Operations on website
        coupon="Something";

    }
    public String getCoupon(){
        if (coupon==null){
            return "";
        }else{
            return coupon;
        }
    }

    public void start (){
        System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
        if (t == null){
            t = new Thread (this, threadName);
            t.start ();
        }
    }

}
```

Now just call it:

```
 ThreadDemo T1 = new ThreadDemo( "Coupon-code");
 T1.start();
 String coupon = "";
 while(coupon.equals("")) //<-This can be tweaked in 
                          //order to consume less memory and be faster
     coupon=T1.getCoupon();
```

Tell me how it worked out!

Comment: Threading is going to make the two scripts run in parallel which is going to make it even harder to track their progress relative to each other. Why would threading help in this situation?

Comment: @JeffC As I understand that's exactly what OP wants, run them in parallel, and continue one when the other closes. Threading is quite useful if you want for example 2 users to interact with each other from different browsers

Comment: No Parralell execution will not help always . Because i need the coupon generation(driver 2 ) to be completed before the order palcement(driver1). And i need to preserve the order of execution

Comment: @surajSr the coupon generation will execute before the driver1 with the code I provided, you have control over execution!

Comment: @Rafael Almeida Yes I tried with the answer and it was working. But later changed the implementation using the same driver instance one after the other. So no need of one thread to wait . Any way this threading was more interesting to try.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm typing on my phone, so you might need to double check the API.

You can use

```
String coupon = couponDriver.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("couponId")).getText(); // or getValue()  depend on element type
```

// continue with shopping driver using the coupon value

Answer (score 0):

@Rafael Almeida Yes I tried with the answer and it was working. But later changed the implementation using the same driver instance one after the other. So no need of one thread to wait . Any way this threading was more interesting to try.